# Background Color Changer with Set List of Colors

Tags: javascript

Needing help with something that *should* be simple. I have this js that generates random background colors...

```
document.body.style.background = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);
```

What I want to do is have a set list of hex colors for it to randomize and I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

With an array of predefined colors, you can get a random color like so :

```
var colors = ['#333', '#111', '#222', '#FFF', '#000', '#F333F3', '#AA00AA'];
document.body.style.background = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MG7a6/)